# Hibernate update setting JoinColumns as null in referenced table for OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to update TableA entity and Hibernate is executing updates on referenced table alongside. It tries to set `null` for the columns referenced in `JoinColumn`

I thought this was due to Cascading. But Disabling `Cascade.ALL` - does not work.

When I set `updatable = false` for both of the `JoinColumn`s - it works.

My question is - why is it trying to do this in the first place?

My tables:

```
TableA: a_id, x_id, some_data
TableB: b_id, a_id, x_id, some_other_data
```

Owner Entity

```
class TableAEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "a_id", nullable=false)
  private int aId;

  @Column(name = "x_id", nullable=false)
  private int xId;

  @Column(name = "some_data", nullable=false)
  private String someData;
  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "x_id", referencedColumnName = "x_id")
  })
  private List<TableBEntity> bEntities;
}
```

The other entity

```
class TableBEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "b_id", nullable=false)
  private int bId;
  
  @Column(name = "a_id", nullable=false)
  private int aId;

  @Column(name = "x_id", nullable=false)
  private int xId;

  @Column(name = "some_other_data", nullable=false)
  private String someOtherData;
}
```

Comment: I would assume this Is this occurring when inserting a new TableBEntity. Since the mapping is 'owned' and the foreign keys entirely controlled by the TableAEntity references, JPA providers can and many will perform the B insert and then later on come back an update the foreign key values when processing the TableAEntity entity mappings - forcing a separate statement. If this is the case, it will insert TableB, update/insert  TableA, then update TableB's foreign keys. You can have it operate as you might expect using a bidirectional mapping, so that the FKs are owned and controlled from TableB

Comment: Your mappings are very wrong though, as you have multiple mappings for tableB's 'a_id' and 'x_id' column. So how do you want this setup - why do you have aId and xId mapped in your TableBEntity? You have to set the values in the TableBEntity instance or they will be null - worse, JPA will set them again based on the TableAEntity.bEntities references and not set the xId/aId java properties for you.